# Create an account on a private stellar network

Tags: accounts, javascript-sdk, private-network

I wish to create an account on a private stellar network. 
The network was created using this docker image `https://github.com/stellar/docker-stellar-core-horizon`, with the `--standalone` flag.

When I attempt to create a network in the following way I receive the error `Network.current(...).networkId is not a function`.

The SDK is connected to the network and I am able to get the network information using `StellarSdk.Network.current()`.

```
stellarServer
  .loadAccount(sourceKey.publicKey())
  .then(sourceAccount => {
    transaction = new StellarSdk.TransactionBuilder(sourceAccount)
      .addOperation(
        StellarSdk.Operation.createAccount({
          destination: dest,
          startingBalance: "100"
        })
      )
      .build();
    transaction.sign(sourceKey);
    return stellarServer.submitTransaction(transaction);
  })
  .then(result => {
    console.log("success" + JSON.stringify(result, undefined, 2));
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log("error" + error);
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to choose your private network first.

```
StellarSdk.Network.use(new StellarSdk.Network('your_private_network_passphrase_here'))
```

Then create an instance of `StellarSdk.Server` using the link to your local Horizon server.

```
let stellarServer = new StellarSdk.Server('http://{horizon_instance_address}:{horizon_port}')
```

And after that you can proceed with your code.

Comment: Thank you. My error was not initiating a new StellarSdk.Network  but rather simply using the passphrase after 
`StellarSdk.Network.use("passphrase")